# Post parameters empty NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express

I just set up a project in NodeJS and I am trying to do a POST request from my frontend (via API). Everything is working fine, the post request is succesfully performed, all the parameters are sent and my NodeJS app gets the request, however the body/params are empty.

Here's the code I am using:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const app = express();


const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type']
}


app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  res.send('Hello World!');
})
```

The app shows 'Hello World' when I post to the the default path and also shows all the `req` information but the parameters are empty `{}`

Here's my client side code:

```
  testPost(parameter1: any, parameter2: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(URL_API.url,
                                {'parameter1': parameter1, 'parameter2': parameter2},
                                {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': '*'})});
  }
```

Here's wat I get in NodeJS:

```
<ref *2> IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: true,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
  },
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: clearRequestTimeout] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [Circular *2],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: ServerResponse {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: true,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: false,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: null,
      _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
      _sent100: false,
      _expect_continue: false,
      req: [Circular *2],
      locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 20,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
      _idleTimeout: -1,
      _idlePrev: null,
      _idleNext: null,
      _idleStart: 2049,
      _onTimeout: null,
      _timerArgs: undefined,
      _repeat: null,
      _destroyed: true,
      [Symbol(refed)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 28,
      [Symbol(triggerId)]: 24
    },
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers: {
    host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
    connection: 'keep-alive',
    'content-length': '66',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'content-type': 'applcation/json',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    referer: 'http://localhost:4200/',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
  },
  rawHeaders: [
    'Host',
    '127.0.0.1:3000',
    'Connection',
    'keep-alive',
    'Content-Length',
    '66',
    'sec-ch-ua',
    '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'Accept',
    'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type',
    'applcation/json',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile',
    '?0',
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform',
    '"Linux"',
    'Origin',
    'http://localhost:4200',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site',
    'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode',
    'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest',
    'empty',
    'Referer',
    'http://localhost:4200/',
    'Accept-Encoding',
    'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language',
    'en-US,en;q=0.9'
  ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  aborted: false,
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client: <ref *1> Socket {
    connecting: false,
    _hadError: false,
    _parent: null,
    _host: null,
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      end: [Array],
      timeout: [Function: socketOnTimeout],
      data: [Function: bound socketOnData],
      error: [Function: socketOnError],
      close: [Array],
      drain: [Function: bound socketOnDrain],
      resume: [Function: onSocketResume],
      pause: [Function: onSocketPause]
    },
    _eventsCount: 8,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: false,
      ended: false,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: false,
      decodeStrings: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: false,
      autoDestroy: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _sockname: null,
    _pendingData: null,
    _pendingEncoding: '',
    server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11
    },
    _server: Server {
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _connections: 1,
      _handle: [TCP],
      _usingWorkers: false,
      _workers: [],
      _unref: false,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      pauseOnConnect: false,
      httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
      timeout: 0,
      keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      headersTimeout: 60000,
      requestTimeout: 0,
      _connectionKey: '4:127.0.0.1:3000',
      [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
      [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 11
    },
    parser: HTTPParser {
      '0': [Function: bound setRequestTimeout],
      '1': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
      '2': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
      '3': [Function: parserOnBody],
      '4': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
      '5': [Function: bound onParserExecute],
      '6': [Function: bound onParserTimeout],
      _headers: [],
      _url: '',
      socket: [Circular *1],
      incoming: [Circular *2],
      outgoing: null,
      maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
      _consumed: true,
      onIncoming: [Function: bound parserOnIncoming],
      [Symbol(resource_symbol)]: [HTTPServerAsyncResource]
    },
    on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
    _paused: false,
    _httpMessage: ServerResponse {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: false,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: true,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: false,
      _headerSent: false,
      socket: [Circular *1],
      _header: null,
      _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
      _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
      _sent100: false,
      _expect_continue: false,
      req: [Circular *2],
      locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 20,
    [Symbol(kHandle)]: TCP {
      reading: true,
      onconnection: null,
      _consumed: true,
      [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
    [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
    [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
      _idleTimeout: -1,
      _idlePrev: null,
      _idleNext: null,
      _idleStart: 2049,
      _onTimeout: null,
      _timerArgs: undefined,
      _repeat: null,
      _destroyed: true,
      [Symbol(refed)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 28,
      [Symbol(triggerId)]: 24
    },
    [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
    [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/',
  _parsedUrl: Url {
    protocol: null,
    slashes: null,
    auth: null,
    host: null,
    port: null,
    hostname: null,
    hash: null,
    search: null,
    query: null,
    pathname: '/',
    path: '/',
    href: '/',
    _raw: '/'
  },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res: <ref *3> ServerResponse {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: true,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: true,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: false,
    socket: <ref *1> Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: null,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 8,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: [Server],
      _server: [Server],
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      on: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      addListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      prependListener: [Function: socketListenerWrap],
      _paused: false,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *3],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 20,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idleStart: 2049,
        _onTimeout: null,
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: true,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 28,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 24
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: null,
    _keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
    _onPendingData: [Function: bound updateOutgoingData],
    _sent100: false,
    _expect_continue: false,
    req: [Circular *2],
    locals: [Object: null prototype] {},
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      'x-powered-by': [Array],
      'access-control-allow-origin': [Array],
      vary: [Array]
    }
  },
  body: {},
  route: Route { path: '/', stack: [ [Layer] ], methods: { post: true } },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]:
```

**So here's my question:** How do I get post parameters in NodeJS?

Comment: Are you sure you want parameters? I'm assuming "post parameters" = request body? If so `req.body` would be what you want and not `req.params`.

Comment: I mean I tried that. It's empty everything and I am sure they are being sent.

Comment: Show your client side code

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I don't know what library you're using to do the post request, but you should probably specify the content type. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` would be for normal post params. json for json as @JastriaRahmat mentioned.

Comment: HttpClientModule Angular. That's a great idea, let me try.

Comment: specify the content type to application/json. then, in express, console log(req.body)

Comment: Yeah now that worked. It was the content type. Sorry. I thought that * would do.

Comment: @NewUser2 for future, `*` is pretty meaningless. You're essentially saying to the server that "the request could contain anything", it's always best to be explicit. `application/json` for example.

Comment: Thank you, @Isolated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments, in client side, you need to specify `content type` explicitly.

for example:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

then in your express app:

```
console.log(req.body)
```

credits to @isolated and @john in the question's comments

Comment: A small detail I didn't pay attention to, especially because it worked with PHP haha. But thank you all @John, Isolated and you.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was a different thing that was causing the problem and it was on the server side.
The following lines solved the issue (in your app.js or index.js) -

```
app.use(
  express.json({
     limit: "50mb",
   })
);
```

Comment: OP is using `app.use(bodyParser.json())` which is exactly the same thing

Comment: @Phil, I know that it is the same thing. But, I wanted to point out that it could also be an issue for some people.